# Not able to upload the png image(logo) using cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am trying to upload a png file using cypress and this is that i have tried so far

```
Cypress.Commands.add('upload_file', (fileName, selector) => {
  return cy.get(selector).then(subject => {
    return cy.fixture(fileName, 'base64')
      .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
      .then(blob => {
        const el = subject[0]
        const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, { type: 'image/png' })
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
        dataTransfer.items.add(testFile)
        el.files = dataTransfer.files
        return subject;
      })
  })
})
```

calling this in my test as below:

```
 cy.upload_file("logo.png", ".jss378");
```

it does not give any error but also it does not upload anything. note that the selector(.jss378) is dynamic so i want to use something that is not dynamic

Here is my HTML code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFak5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using cypress upload plugin

here are the steps:

1) adding the following in the command.js:

```
import 'cypress-file-upload';
```

2) and using this in the test:

```
// uploading the brand logo
    const fileName = 'logo.png';

cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('[title="Logo"]').upload(
    { fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'image/png' },
    { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' },
  );
});
```

documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/index.html#content